# Copy items from sql database table to SharePoint list

Tags: database

I need to migrate items from SQLdatabase table to SharePoint list. I know this can be achieved using a C# console, but I have no idea how to achieve this. 
(Need to implement this using C# code, I know BCS can be used, but i don't want to use that)

Any help on this will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Update your question with following - SP version, is it on prem or online, whether the list is existing or new, you need this for an one time migration or is it continuous integration.

Comment: Do you want it to be one time activity ?

Comment: Yes, This is one time activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these 2 namespaces :

- `using System.Data.SqlClient;`
- `using Microsoft.SharePoint;`

Add this code and call GetData method

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [DATABASENAME].[dbo].[TABLENAME] WHERE [ID] IS NOT NULL";
            DataSet ds = getDataFromSQL(query, CommandType.Text);
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0] != null & ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    using(SPSite site = new SPSite("siteUrl"))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("");
                            if (list != null)
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                                {
                                    SPListItem item = list.AddItem();
                                    item["colName1"] = Convert.ToString(dr["colName"]);
                                    item["colName2"] = Convert.ToString(dr["colName"]);
                                    //... And so on
                                    item.Update();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private DataSet getDataFromSQL(string dbQuery, CommandType dbType)
    {
        DataSet dsToReturn = null;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "your connection string here";

            using (SqlConnection dsConnection = connection)
            {
                try { dsConnection.Open(); }
                catch { }
                using (SqlCommand dsCommand = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    dsCommand.CommandType = dbType;
                    dsCommand.CommandText = dbQuery;
                    dsCommand.Connection = dsConnection;

                    SqlDataAdapter daToFillDataSet = new SqlDataAdapter(dsCommand);
                    dsToReturn = new DataSet();
                    daToFillDataSet.Fill(dsToReturn);
                    //dsConnection.Close();
                    //dsCommand.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception){
            return dsToReturn;
        }
        return dsToReturn;
    }
```

You will need to update connection string, database name, table name, column name

Comment: welcome @Muskan

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple example to retrieve items from SQLdatabase table to SharePoint list

1. Create a function to get your data from SQL server and return it as a data table.

   ```
   // your method to pull data from database to datatable   
   public DataTable GetDatafromSQL()
   {
       DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();            
       string connString = @"your connection string here";
       string query = "select * from table";

       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
       conn.Open();

       // create data adapter
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
       da.Fill(dataTable);
       conn.Close();
       da.Dispose();
       return dataTable;
   }
   ```
2. Create a function that adds items to list and loop for every item at the retrieved SQL data table.

   ```
    void Addnewitem()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt= GetDatafromSQL();

    using (SPSite oSite=new SPSite("http://mysharepoint"))
     {

      using (SPWeb oWeb=oSite.RootWeb)
       {
           SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Test"];
           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
           {
           SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();
           oSPListItem["Title"] = dr["Title"].ToString();
           oSPListItem.Update();
           }
       }

    }
   ```

**Note:** I considered that the data structure that will retrieve from SQL is already matched with List Structure.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx)

or you can syncronize the db table data to sharePoint list using BCS also
Below link help you with that
[How to sync a SQL database with a SharePoint List?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/how-to-sync-a-sql-database-with-a-sharepoint-list)

Comment: I want to use C# code to copy the items, any idea about that.