# C# Bind SQL Server Table in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, development, sql-server-2012, databind

I want to copy sql server table in sharepoint 2010list, I know that Business Data Connectivity Service (BDC) might do it, but I have some problems and it doesn't work, so I want to do it programmatically.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Are you trying to make the data in SQL *available* from SharePoint?  Or, are you trying to *clone* the data from SQL in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple example to retrieve Records from SQLdatabase table to SharePoint list

1. Create a function to get your data from SQL server and return it to a data table.

   ```
   // your method to pull data from database to datatable   
   public DataTable GetDatafromSQL()
   {
       DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();            
       string connString = @"your connection string here";
       string query = "select * from table";

       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
       conn.Open();

       // create data adapter
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
       da.Fill(dataTable);
       conn.Close();
       da.Dispose();
       return dataTable;
   }
   ```
2. Create a function that loop for every item at the retrieved SQL data table and adds it to list.

   ```
    void binditems()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt= GetDatafromSQL();

    using (SPSite oSite=new SPSite("http://mysharepoint"))
     {

      using (SPWeb oWeb=oSite.RootWeb)
       {
           SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Test"];
           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
           {
           SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();
           oSPListItem["Title"] = dr["Title"].ToString();
           oSPListItem.Update();
           }
       }
    }
    }
   ```

Read the Function `binditems()`, to can bind the data from SQL to List

**Note** : don't forget to include this namespaces `using System.Data.SqlClient;`    `using Microsoft.SharePoint;`

Check also [How to achieve this in a windows application Using SharePoint Server Object Model](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/03/01/using-sharepoint-server-object-model-in-windows-application/)

Check also [Copy items from sql database table to SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193631/copy-items-from-sql-database-table-to-sharepoint-list/)

Comment: it works, thankx again, last question, if I want to edit from sharepoint list , and see it in sql table , what should I do ?

Comment: Dear @BKChedlia in this case,  you should create Event receiver on item update via visual studio , then get the related item in sql table then update item with Update sql statement. please tell me if you need a reference to do this ,

Comment: I will try the event receiver, but you can please help me with a reference or exemple . thankx again

Comment: I noticed a problem, when I call my code binditems() from the page load (I put it in webpart), it repeat the items each time I hit f5

Comment: Hey @BKChedlia regarding event reciver check http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/06/27/creating-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2010/ and https://seminda.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/creating-sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45739/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-bkchedlia).

Comment: Regarding f5 , try  to yes if (!this.Page.IsPostBack) on page load event ,please don't hesitate to tell me  if you need more details , at  chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45739/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-bkchedlia